# RestKit Mapping multiple root objects ONLY on Post/Put

Tags: ios, restkit

I fetch lots of objects at separate resource paths, and have the mappings set up appropriately for those.

However when I post a new object (eg. guest-card) it contains other objects (interactions, tenants). As such, the response data has multiple root objects guestcard/tenants/​interactions. I chose this method instead of nesting the serialized response as it more closely matches how I normally fetch and parse things (as separate objects.)

How can I handle this as a one off mapping? I'm figuring I can somehow do this using one of the new block methods like - (void)postObject:(id​)object usingBlock:(void(^)(RKObjectLo​ader *))block

Can I setup an anonymous mapping that just points the various root keys to the right class mappings?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that when you use the `postObject` or `putObject` method, RestKit is automatically going to try to map the json result into the sourceObject that was posted. Per Blake, this is necessary for the non Core Data backed objects so that you don't have to instantiate a whole new object.

However in my scenario where I'm trying to map 3 top level json keys into existing mappings with core data backed objects, it didn't make sense.

It turns out what you need to do is nil out the `targetObject`, and then the standard key-value-coding mapping will take over (assuming your root objects are keyed correctly in the json).

If you still need the delegate methods to fire, you can set loader.delegate

```
        [objectManager postObject:guestCard usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
            loader.targetObject = nil;
            loader.delegate = self;
        }];
```